# Cannot convert value of type '(year: Int, month:Int,day:int)' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: xcode

I was making a little program to make a family with classes and suddenly i got the error Cannot convert value of type '(year: Int, month:Int,day:int)' to expected argument type 'String'. I'm still thinking but i'm not sure what's the matter. Can anyone help? (I'm using the language Swift 2)

```html
import UIKit


class persone {
    var age : Int = 1
    let name : String
    var height : Double = 1.6
    let hairColor : String
    var birthday : (year: Int,month : Int, day : Int) = (2007,12,18)
    
    init(age: Int, name: String, height: Double, hairColor: String, birthday: String){
        self.age = age
        self.name=name
        self.height = height
        self.hairColor = hairColor
        let a = birthday.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
        self.birthday = (Int(a[0])!,Int(a[1])!,Int(a[2])!)
        
    }
    func howOld()->Int{
    return age-birthday.year
    }
    
    
}


class grandma : person{
 
    let sex : String = "female"
    init(name : String, birthday : String, height :Double ,hairColor : String ) {
        super.init(age: self.age, name: self.name, height: self.height, hairColor: self.hairColor, birthday: self.birthday)
    }



}







class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The error is in the class 'Grandma' under where it says let sex : String = "female"

Comment: i'm using swift 2 if you want to copy paste

Comment: can anyone help